# How to implement bit_and in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have an implementation where I am using this
case when bit_and(cast(sm.numbermask as int) & 32) = 32 then true else false end AS abc_flag. This seems to work on Athena which uses presto but when I use spark.sql() to run this, this function isn't recognized. Can someone help with similar function?

Tried using bit_and but not sure about its implementation

Answer (score 0):

bool_and is the equivalent of bit_and in Spark Sql

```
SELECT bool_and(col) FROM VALUES (true), (true), (true) AS tab(col);
 true
> SELECT bool_and(col) FROM VALUES (NULL), (true), (true) AS tab(col);
 true
> SELECT bool_and(col) FROM VALUES (true), (false), (true) AS tab(col);
 false
```